# Any applications for minimizing the Neural Network functions?

Tags: optimization, machine-learning, nonlinear-optimization, neural-networks

I wonder if there are any theoretical/practical (paper) applications for minimizing a Neural Network function?

Precisely, let $f(w,x)$ be a real-valued neural network function obtained by determining its weights. Now I am interested in minimizing $f(w,x)$ over all $x$ in some space! Is there any application for this minimization?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose you want to minimize a function $F(\mathbf{x})$. The function may be very expensive to evaluate (e.g., a computer simulation model which takes a couple of hours to complete), and/or its functional form and/or its gradients may not be available. In that case, you may evaluate the function at $N$ points and collect the pairs $(\mathbf{x}_{1}, y_{1})$,...,$(\mathbf{x}_{N}, y_{N})$, where $y_{i}:=F(\mathbf{x}_{i})$. Using the data pairs $(\mathbf{x}_{i}, y_{i}), i=1,..,N$, you may train a neural network $f$ and find a mapping $f(\mathbf{x}_{i} \mid \mathbf{w}) = y_{i} +  \epsilon$. Now, if you minimize $f(\mathbf{x} \mid \mathbf{w})$, you can take $\mathbf{x}^{*} = \arg \min_{\mathbf{x}} f(\mathbf{x} \mid \mathbf{w})$ as your next evaluation point (i.e., $N+1^{th}$ point) for $F$. Then, with the observed $y_{N+1}$, you may re-train the neural network and repeat the process.

The idea is that the neural network $f$ will be a surrogate of $F$, and will assist you through finding $\min_{\mathbf{x}} F(\mathbf{x})$. This approach is known as Surrogate Optimization. Some of the commonly used surrogate models are RBF interpolant (see e.g., Regis and Shoemaker, 2007), Gaussian Process (e.g., Bayesian Optimization), Decision Tree, NN, SVM.

Comment: Could you please narrow your suggestion by putting a link? I don't mean training an nn, as it brought up on every search, I mean to minimize a neural network function itself.

Comment: Just updated my answer.

Comment: I voted up your question to appreciate the time you put into writing the answer. But it didn't even help me to find a solution. I'm fully aware of Surogate optimization. Basically, in practice, everything is based on a surrogate! That's the motivation of my question. I need a precise reference showing somewhere to consider an nn function and minimizing it. In your all reference, I see they just talk about approximation but minimizing nn for a particular reason. I want to cite it in a paper. I have to be precise. Like exactly for what problem they made trained nn and then minimize it

Comment: I have found review papers for the application of NN surrogates in the domain of aerodynamic design optimization (https://doi.org/10.1177/0954410019864485) and water treatment (https://doi.org/10.1029/2011WR011527).